# Is there any way to pass a callback to a function in WGSL?

Tags: function, callback, wgsl

I can't seem to figure out how or if it is acually possible to pass acallback to a function in WGSL. I would like to make something along these lines.

```
fn foo(x: f32, bar: ?callback?) {
    bar(x);
}


fn baz(y: f32) -> f32 {
    return y + 1;
}

@compute 
fn main() {
    foo(5, baz) // => 6
}
```

My intelisense hinted me

```
bar: Fn
```

but compiler doesn't like that.

Comment: How is this related to Rust? As far as I know WGSL just uses a very similar syntax‽

Comment: I am using wgsl library, so I thought whis would be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WGSL does not have function pointers, so you can't pass a function as a parameter.

Comment: Well.. Great. I thought that would be the case. Already rewritten the code. Thanks!